# How to deal with text overflow in fixed height container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was just thinking, that is there a way to deal with text overflow with dynamic text in a fixed height layout?

I often see when I have to sitebuild for backend developers, that there is a fixed height container/layer (Like a card or thubnail) where you can't use the `overflow: auto`
css property becouse the design is not allowing it.

Let us assume that I would use `ellipsis`, but the text can be in 2 lines long.
I could use the `:after` or `:before` pseudo but what if the dots I created will be overflown on the text, or pushed out of the container?
If I use Javascript and maximalize the characters number, than it will break the world like this: `Hello worl...` .
Yeah sure, we can maximalize the characters in the backend side in each field, but sometimes it won't work properly in smaller devices (Tablet, mobile).

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5xun06t/4/) if I didn't tell in a good way, what I'm thinking about.

My question is, what is the best practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

did you try line-clamp

```
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

look into this url for more help
[Line Clampin’ (Truncating Multiple Line Text)](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)